# Ubuntu VirtualBox Graphical Glitches/Black Screens

Tags: 16.04, graphics, virtualbox

The windowing system in Ubuntu has off and on problems for me. I've had to restart X a few times (from another terminal) losing all my work which has been a real pain. What can I do to fix these problems or more gracefully recover when I need to restart X? Forgive any improper terminology, I'm new to Ubuntu.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in VirtualBox. I have 3D Acceleration enabled. I have an Intel i7 running with the Integrated HD Graphics. My host OS is Windows 7.

The problems are all graphical but vary in intensity. Some I can work with and some I can't. The keyboard and mouse still seem to function no matter how bad it glitches out.
Here's one example where the window control icons are black.
[image]

I've had it sometimes that it will replace title bar drop down menu titles with stretched icon pictures. I've had it get stuck at a black screen. I've also had it get stuck like this.

[image]

I have only successfully recovered once and that was by manually telling VirtualBox to reset the display size and everything came back. This hasn't worked in other instances. Running `sudo service lightdm restart` always fixes the problem but I also lose my work. There seems to be some small correlation between Chromium (and possibly WebGL) and these issues but they have occurred in other instances.

Comment: Have you installed the guest additions?

Comment: @CelticWarrior Yes.

Comment: Turning off 3D Acceleration so far seems to be more stable but I want to give it a couple days.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue was the enabled 3D acceleration and my VM is now much more stable to the point where I haven't had any glitches since.

The only issue now is that my 3D applications run much slower.